# I am getting error about email in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-mail

I have a problem to solve. However, this problem came to me from sentry.io. So I didn't see the problem directly.

The problem is as follows: `Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tKY8.png)

The problem with sentry.io is in the picture. However, as far as I understand, the problem is not directly caused by this file. In other words, the problem is in sending mail, so since email is used here, it shows the problem here. I have not used services such as laravel mailing before, so I have no idea right now.

I can share with you the necessary codes, files, etc., so that we can better understand the problem.

Comment: ```Mail::to($user->email)```, isn't it ?

Comment: @フクちゃん How should I change the selected line in the photo like this?

Comment: you need to go ```EmailCronJobController.php``` file

Comment: @フクちゃん Ok, now this file is in front of me. 
```foreach ($users as $user){
            if($user->getCustomField('nothing_listened_3_days_email_send_date')==null){
                Mail::to($user)->send(new NothingListenedFor3Days($user));
                $user->setCustomField('nothing_listened_3_days_email_send_date',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            }```

Comment: change `Mail::to($user)` to `Mail::to($user->email)`

Answer (score 0):

**Send Mail**

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NothingListenedFor3Days($user));
```

**Mail Class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NothingListenedFor3Days extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Your Subject')
            ->view('Your blade file path')->with('user',$this->user);
    }
}
```

[For reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530566/address-in-mailbox-given-does-not-comply-with-rfc-2822-3-6-2-when-email-is)

Comment: Hi, I shared what I did as an answer below. I would be very happy if you could look at it and tell me if there is any mistake. @Ali Raza

Answer (score 0):

@Ali Raza
I made both files as I shared below. Are there any mistakes I've made?

**EmailCronJobController.php**

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NothingListenedFor3Days($user));
```

**NothingListenedFor3Days.php**

```
namespace App\Mail\Listener;

use App\Course;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NothingListenedFor3Days extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $listener;
    public $random_contents;
    public $fromEmail = 'listener@omnicourse.io';
    public $fromName = 'Omnicourse';
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $listener)
    {
        $this->listener = $listener;
        $this->random_contents = Course::all()->random(10);
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->fromEmail,$this->fromName)
            ->view('email.listener.nothing_listened_for_3_days')->with('user',$this->listener);
            ->text('email.listener.nothing_listened_for_3_days_plain')
            ->subject("Let's move ahead together");
    }
}
```