# I get an error: Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project at hand. However, I did not write this project. They gave me a bug to solve. It shows the problem in this file `/app/Http/Controllers/Crons/EmailCronJobController.php` but as far as I understand, it shows here because sending mail is used here. I have not used such services of Laravel before, so I do not know much. I'm putting the screenshot of the problem and the content of the file below, but if there is something different I need to share for you to understand better, I can share it with you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAiNZ.png)

**EmailCronJobController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Crons;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Mail\Listener\FirstContentListen;
use App\Mail\Listener\NothingListenedFor3Days;
use App\RawListeningData;
use App\User;
use App\UserPayment;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EmailCronJobController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $this->listeners();
    }

    private function listeners(){
        $this->listenersFirstContentListen();
        $this->listenersNothingListenedFor3Days();
    }

    private function listenersNothingListenedFor3Days(){
        $users = User::where([
            ['role_id','=', 4],
            ['created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay(7)->toDateTimeString()],
            ['created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDay(3)->toDateTimeString()]
            ])->get();
        $users = $users->filter(function ($user){
            return $user->getFirstListenedContent()==null;
        });
        /*
        foreach ($users as $user){
            $email_array = explode('@',$user->email);
            $email = $email_array[0].'@etrexio.com';
            $user->update(['email'=>$email]);
        }*/
        foreach ($users as $user){
            if($user->getCustomField('nothing_listened_3_days_email_send_date')==null){
                 Mail::to($user)->send(new NothingListenedFor3Days($user));
                $user->setCustomField('nothing_listened_3_days_email_send_date',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            }
        }
    }

    private function testEmail(){
        $active_user_payments = UserPayment::select('user_id')->where('exprire_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())->get();
        $active_users_ids = $active_user_payments->map(function ($payments){
            return $payments->user_id;
        });
        $users = User::whereIn('id',$active_users_ids)->get();
        dd($users);
    }

    private function listenersFirstContentListen(){
        $last_24_h_listening = RawListeningData::select('user_id')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateTimeString())->get();
        $last_24_h_listening_users = $last_24_h_listening->map(function ($listening){
            return $listening->user_id;
        })->unique();
        $before_24_h_listening = RawListeningData::select('user_id')->whereIn('user_id',$last_24_h_listening_users)->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDay()->toDateTimeString())->get();
        $before_24_h_listening_users = $before_24_h_listening->map(function ($listening){
            return $listening->user_id;
        })->unique();
        $result = collect($last_24_h_listening_users)->diff(collect($before_24_h_listening_users));
        $users = User::whereIn('id',$result)->get();
        foreach ($users as $user){
            if($user->getCustomField('first_content_listen_email_send_date')==null){
                $content = $user->getFirstListenedContent();
                if($content!=null){
                    Mail::to($user)->send(new FirstContentListen($user,$content));
                    $user->setCustomField('first_content_listen_email_send_date',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NothingListenedFor3Days.php**

```
namespace App\Mail\Listener;

use App\Course;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NothingListenedFor3Days extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $listener;
    public $random_contents;
    public $fromEmail = 'listener@omnicourse.io';
    public $fromName = 'Omnicourse';
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $listener)
    {
        $this->listener = $listener;
        $this->random_contents = Course::all()->random(10);
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->fromEmail,$this->fromName)
            ->view('email.listener.nothing_listened_for_3_days')
            ->text('email.listener.nothing_listened_for_3_days_plain')
            ->subject("Let's move ahead together");
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Did you check whether the mail address is  a valid one?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, the e-mail (listener@omnicourse.io) address is valid.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for the proper part of your code? Is the recipients address also valid?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, the recipient address is also valid.

Comment: Then, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not step through the execution of your code to see which input triggers that problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase Obviously, the problem is not something that happens all the time. In other words, once or twice a day, sometimes sentry.io never drops. So I don't fully understand what triggered the problem.

Comment: Then please check this further. I would assume that any of the recipients' addresses is invalid

Comment: @NicoHaase Ok, I'll check again in detail. Besides, is there anything else you can suggest to me?

Comment: Would `Mail::to($user)` work? I would expect you'd need something like `Mail::to($user->email)` or something

Comment: Currently not. Debugging the problem and checking which input triggers the problem should be the first case. Afterwards, you need to check for invalid inputs and reject the mail sending process for them

Comment: @apokryfos Should I change the EmailCronJobController.php file as you say?

Comment: I do apologise, my post was incorrect

Comment: It couldn't hurt to try I guess

Comment: @migsAV It's okay mate. If there's anything you think will help me figure it out, you can share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably this line:

```
            Mail::to($user)>send(newFirstContentListen($user,$content));
```

$user in your case it's an object not email. Try to debug it or dd() at several points to see where it get stucks.

Also might want to check this out

[Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. when email is in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530566/address-in-mailbox-given-does-not-comply-with-rfc-2822-3-6-2-when-email-is)

Comment: That won't explain why this works sometimes, and fails at other times

Comment: It does explain. It's wrapped inside an if condition and it will not always enter inside there

Comment: So, some mails get sent out properly by this line, and some are not?

Comment: No, incorrect. In other uses cases the email is formatted properly and won't throw error. In the other case, when the condition is true, it will go there and the $user will be an object not email

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @workservice I was in a meeting, I couldn't answer you. What exactly should I do now? Frankly, I'm a little confused. What should I do or try as a solution or is there anything I should pass on so that I can assist you?

Comment: @NicoHaase What do you think about this situation?

Comment: Why not check for the root cause of the error, like recommended some hours ago?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have already checked the sender e-mail address and the recipient e-mail address, there is no problem with it. Other than that, I don't know exactly where to check as I don't know what the root cause of the error is. If you tell me to check that place, I will take care of it right away. I know I'm boring you because I'm new to this stuff. But I'm trying to understand too, :)

Comment: @iguner you should pass the user email in that case, not only the user object and it will be okay

Comment: @workservice like this: `Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NothingListenedFor3Days($user));` is it true?

Comment: Yep you can try that.  Check both Mail::to() Any place that should store email and you are not passing it, replace it with an email. You could also replace it with email string just for test purposes and then replace them back with actual code. Debug is your friend

Comment: @workservice OK, I'll try. Thank you very much for your help, but if I fail, I will write to you again here, please do not be angry with me.

Comment: all good, happy to help!